# Access and VB6 application - from single to multiuser

Tags: vb6

Recently I have been asked to take care of a single-user VB6 application that accesses Access database. The database is located in the same directory as that of the exe file. Now, it is required that several (around 5 more) users need simultaneous access to this application. So, should I place the database in a network location and change the connection code in the application so that the application can access it from various user consoles? I want that the database should be totally away from the reach of the users and they have no clue what/where the database is. How to do this?

Comment: A couple of additional items to concern yourself with - depending on how the code reads and writes to the database, you might run into contention issues that'll need to be resolved - for instance if a table or other object is open as write-able (locked) for an extended time, other users trying to read or write it will receive an error. Also, if the users are WAN remote to the mdb database you're more likely to have timing, timeout and contention issues - with an Access mdb you will see much better performance to have it LAN (not WAN) accessible.

Comment: The database will remain in LAN. No WAN access.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you share the folder on the server with a hidden share by putting the '$' sign at the end of the share name , and provide the necessary rights to users .
and in the connection string you specify your path as :

```
strServeur = "IP of your server\name_of_your_shared_folder$"
strDriver = "{SQL Server}" 'Driver pour l'accès à la database
Set oConn = New ADODB.Connection
oConn.Open "Driver=" & strDriver & ";" & _
"Server=" & strServeur & ";" & _
"Database=" & strDataBase & ";" & _
"Uid=" & paramCon.userBd & ";" & _
"Pwd=" & paramCon.passBd & ";"
```

Comment: Security by obscurity?  That's a hack that may make things simple but you'd be better off adding a middle tier.  Or the caveman's way out: just use a client/server DBMS instead of Jet (you are not using "MS Access" unless you are automating an instance of Access - a thought that makes me cringe).